# Clarification needed about EBS-optimized, IOPS and Throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, throughput, provisioned-iops

I'm studying the [Amazon EBS–optimized instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html) document trying to apply it to a specific scenario.

I'm using a `c6a.2xlarge` instance with a single `gp3` volume (2 TB) attached. According to the document the `c6a.2xlarge` instance is listed as one of *those instance types that support maximum performance for only 30 minutes at least once every 24 hours*.

About the baseline performance of `c6a.2xlarge`, the second table says the following:

- Baseline throughput=265.25 MB/s
- Baseline IOPS=8333

About the maximum performance of `c6a.2xlarge`, the first table says the following:

- Maximum throughput=833.333 MB/s
- Maximum IOPS=26667

On the other side, the `gp3` volume can be configured with:

- Min: 125 MiB, Max: 1000 MiB. Baseline: 125 MiB/s per TiB.
- Min: 3000 IOPS, Max: 16000 IOPS

I have a workload that requires sustained maximum performance for longer than 30 minutes, but I cannot afford a different instance.

I'm trying to intersect the information reported above, so my questions are:

1. If I modify the `gp3` volume with exactly 265 MB/s of throughput and 8333 IOPS I'm almost guaranteed to have such performance 24/7 ?
2. Is there any benefit in increasing the throughput up to 833 MB/s and/or the IOPS up to 16000 given the fact that such performance can be sustained just for max 30 minutes in 24 hours ?